# phpMailer sending attachment name, not attachment

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

Hi I have a file upload field with name="file1" and code in a phpmailer script:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file1']))
{
$file1_path = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$file1_name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$file1_type = $_FILES['file1']['type'];
$file1_error = $_FILES['file1']['error'];
$mail->AddAttachment($file1_path);
}
```

And for some reason, it attached like php45we34 (each time diff, seems that its the temp name path, not the actual file)

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use function move_uploaded_file before adding attachment.

This is sample code that will move file from temporary location somewhere at your server

```
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

After that AddAttachment should work fine.

```
$mail->AddAttachment(basename($target_path . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']));
```

Comment: That looks great. The only thing is that i want to have many file uploads. (file1, file2, file3). Is there any way that i could name each one the same thing, and only run the block of code in php once?

Comment: @user845311 you could use different name attributes for each file in your form, e.g. `file1`, `file2`, etc. and server-side use a loop like `foreach ($_FILES as $key => $file){...}` and inside the loop you would use `$file['tmp_name']` etc.

Comment: @Ovidiu Ok i gotcha. But what would i use for .basename($_FILES... ? And for the addattachment?

Comment: @user845311 basically what you have to do is put all the code in this answer into a loop and inside the loop, instead using `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['some_index']` you would only use `$file['some_index']`. No other changes needed.

Comment: @Ovidiu Almost there. I got the file to save in the uploads folder, but when it tries to email, i get the following error: Could not find Blue hills.jpgBlue hills.jpg file on filesystem. Why is it duplicating the name? Heres my code.. `$mail->AddAttachment(basename($target_path . $file['name']));` Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @user845311 after a second look to the code in this answer it looks like you only need to use `$mail->AddAttachment($target_path);`

Comment: @Ovidiu I have been working on this for two days straigh not exagerration. And finally! Thanks to you! Its working!!!! Much much appreciated. Now i have one other little issue but that is for another forum. Thanks!!!!!!!!! :)

Comment: I would say thanks to @Norbert who provided this answer. I only helped a little.

Answer (score 2):

Strip spaces from your filename!

`Blue hills.jpg` should be `Blue_hills.jpg`

do

`$fileName = str_replace(' ', '_', $fileName);`

Comment: It hasn't really to do with the OP's problems, but it is a good suggestion: +1

Answer (score 1):

What you see is what should happen. [You do not specify the attachment name](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/wp/wp-includes/PHPMailer.class.html#det_methods_AddAttachment), so phpMailer uses the name of the temporary file it's attaching.

If you want the file to have a different name, you have to specify it. The accepted answer works because it goes the other way round -- it changes the file name so that the file has the desired name.

The usual way to proceed would be to issue

```
$mail->AddAttachment($file1_path, $_FILES['file1']['name']);
```

to override the attachment name.